# Attempt to read property "produits" on null

Tags: php, laravel, logic, laravel-8

I want to add to the wishlist; after I click add, I get an error. I believe that the way I want to access the product is wrong.

```
public function addToFavorie($id)
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    $product = produit::find($id);

    if (!$product || !$user) {
        abort(404);
    }

    // I believe this is the part responsible for the error
    $favorie = $user->favorie;
    $favprds = $favorie->produits;
    //

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($favprds); $i++) {
        if ($favprds[$i]->id == $id)
            return redirect()->back()
                ->with('error', 'produit deja dans votre favorie');
    }
    $favorie->produits()->attach($product->id);

    return redirect()->back()->with('info', 'produit ajoute a votre favorie');
}
```

**Model**

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo("App\Models\User");
}

public function produits()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Produit', 'produits_favories');
}
```

I tried this in the controller, and it returned 404.

```
$user = Auth::user()->favorie;
$product = produit::find($id);

if (!$product || !$user) {
    abort(404);
}

$favprds = $favorie->produits;
```

Comment: `$favorie` is null, so you need to check on `$user->favorie`

Comment: i'm sorry i can't follow, can you show me how to check ? thank you

Comment: This line `$favorie = $user->favorie;` is not returning an object so this line `$favprds = $favorie->produits; ` gives an error

Comment: `$user->favorie` is returning `null`, therefore you can't get the product off of it. You'll need to either find out why it's returning null if you think it shouldn't, or check for null before you do anything else with that.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Using "belongsToMany" in
`public function produits() { return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Produit', 'produits_favories'); }`
use "hasMany" like this
`public function produits() { return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Produit', 'produits_favories'); }`
It should work

Comment: it return the same error sir i don't know what do anymore

Answer (score 0):

```
public function addToFavorie($id)
{
    $product = produit::findOrFail($id);

    $favorie = Favorie::firstOrCreate([
        'user_id' => auth()->id()
    ], [
        /* attributes for a `Favorie` instance */
    ]);
    $favorie->produits()->syncWithoutDetaching($product->id);

    return redirect()->back()->with('info', 'produit ajoute a votre favorie');
}
```